# How to run a command process with C#

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I want to run a command process with C# and see the version of NodeJS

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
                           { 
                             FileName="cmd.exe", 
                             Arguments = "node -v"
                           }))
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

but I only see a command prompt without NodeJS version, any idea? thanks

Comment: Try `Arguments = "/c \"node -v\""`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd

Comment: Doesn't `cmd.exe` need `/C` to run a command?  Try `Arguments = "/C node -v"`

Comment: So, you want to run `node`. Why are you adding the middle man of `cmd` into the mix - you're already able to run arbitrary programs using the code you're showing above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C node -v",
}))
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```